# .png not always displayed in Safari

Tags: image, wordpress, safari, png, graphical-logo

I have a problem with my header logo image on WordPress, It's not always displayed on Safari (chrome is OK) and I don't understand why…
I have disable all my plugin and I have tested on others computers… same problem !

link : http://beau-velo.com/WordPress/

Here is some code :

```
.site-header .site-title a,
.site-header .site-title img {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
}

.site-header .site-title a, .site-header .site-title img {
display: block;
}

img {
border: 0;
max-width: 100%;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

thanks in advance,

T.

Comment: Well, it is displayed correctly in my safari 6.0.3. Maybe you need to wait until the page fully loaded.

Comment: Ok cool… I tested with two différents mac and the logo is not displayed on all pages, weird !